# Looping a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to create 20 boxes on screen. i figured a for loop would work. I am using javascript, i can't figure out why its not working. I know my function works, just not sure how to get the loop to work.

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++){
function generateSquare(){
var parent = document.querySelector('.squares');
var squareNode = document.createElement("div");
squareNode.classList.add('square');
parent.appendChild(squareNode);
squareNode.style.top = getRandomInt(0, 400) +'px';
squareNode.style.left = getRandomInt(0, 400) +'px';
squareNode.style.background = 'rgb(' + getRandomInt(0, 255) + ',' + getRandomInt(0, 255) + ',' + getRandomInt(0, 255) + ')';

}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the function inside your loop, but you should be defining it outside the loop and calling it within the loop.

```
// define the function
function generateSquare(){
    var parent = document.querySelector('.squares');
    var squareNode = document.createElement("div");
    squareNode.classList.add('square');
    parent.appendChild(squareNode);
    squareNode.style.top = getRandomInt(0, 400) +'px';
    squareNode.style.left = getRandomInt(0, 400) +'px';
    squareNode.style.background = 'rgb(' + getRandomInt(0, 255) + ',' + getRandomInt(0, 255) + ',' + getRandomInt(0, 255) + ')';
}

for (i=0; i<20; i++){
    // call the function
    generateSquare();
}
```